# bash script for formatting piped output

Tags: linux, bash

Okay, you asked for it - here is my whole code that I am trying to work with.

The help I need with is this:
postprocauto.sh: a script that presents the data in a nice readable format.

I am supposed to take a cat of the autocsv file (sample below - full file is 160k) and then pipe it through various other scripts so in the end, you will have this command line:

```
cat autocsv | ./ prepprocauto.sh | ./BMW.sh | ./6cyl.sh | ./hwyfe.sh | ./postprocauto.sh
```

My problem is that I can get everything to run except the postprocauto.ch.  I need to be able to do this:

```
Requirements for this script:
It must print header information after 20 lines of data. 

The breaks must have a least one empty line between them 
before printing another header. 

The last line of the output should print out the number of 
records that were processed.
```

An example of the output:

```
Year Eng. Disp. Cyl. City FE Hwy FE Model
2013 1.5 4     39 38       ILX
2013 2    4    24 35      ILX
2013 2.4 4     22 31      ILX
2013 2.4 4      22 31      TSX
2013 2.4 4      21 29      TSX
2013 3.5 6      19 28      TSX
2013 1.3 4      41 44      INSIGHT
2013 1.3 4      41 44      INSIGHT
2013 3.5 6      20 29     TL 2WD
2013 3.7 6      18 26     TL 4WD
2013 3.7    6      17 25     TL 4WD
There were 11 records processed.
```

the different scripts are below - if you want the full size autocsv, tell me where to put it - 520k file size

prepprocauto.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x
do
    echo $x | awk -F',' ' { print $1":"$2":"$4":"$7":"$8":"$10":"$11":"$12":"$22":"$24}'

done
```

BMW.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

selection='BMW'

if [ ! $# -lt 1 ]; then
    selection=$1
fi


while read y; do

    model=$(echo $y | awk -F':'  '{print $2 }')

    if [ "$model" == "$selection" ]; then
            echo $y
    fi
done
```

6cyl.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

selection='6'

if [ ! $# -lt 1 ]; then
    selection=$1
fi


while read y; do

    model=$(echo $y | awk -F':'  '{print $5 }')

    if [ "$model" == "$selection" ]; then
            echo $y
    fi
done
```

hwyfe.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

selection='31'

if [ ! $# -lt 1 ]; then
    selection=$1
fi


while read y; do

    hwy=$(echo $y | awk -F':'  '{print $7 }')

    if [ "$hwy" -gt "$selection" ]; then
            echo $y
    fi
done
```

postprocauto.sh

```
output=$(awk -F ':' '{print $1 "\t" $4 "\t"$5"\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $3}')
echo "Year  Eng. Disp Cyl  City FE  Hwy FE   Model"
echo "$output"
```

Contents of the autocsv file (cut down a lot)

```
2013,Audi,Audi,TT Roadster quattro,ADX,67,2,4,Auto(AM-S6),22,31,26,28.4068,42.25
79,33.3217,22.407,31.1674,25.6515,,TC,Turbocharged,AMS,Automated Manual- Selecta
ble (e.g. Automated Manual with paddles),6,Y,N,A,10,GP,Gasoline (Premium Unleade
d Recommended),MPG,N,,,,,,,2200,2200,2,2,1,Two Seaters,car,Vehicle Specific 5-cy
cle label,6/18/12,12113,,N,N,,,N,N,ENGINE CODE CDMA ONLY.,N,,Y,CONTINUOUS VARIAB
LE VALVE TIMING,N,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GDI,Spark Ignition Direct Injection,
N,N,5W40,33.3,7,7,,DADXV02.03UA,5,600,
2013,BMW,BMW,Z4 sDrive28i,BMX,428,2,4,Auto(A8),22,33,26,27.9499,46.8923,34.1594,
21.9803,33.2305,25.9308,,TC,Turbocharged,A,Automatic,8,Y,N,R,10,GP,Gasoline (Pre
mium Unleaded Recommended),MPG,N,,,,,,,2200,2200,2,2,1,Two Seaters,car,Derived 5
-cycle label,7/24/12,11033,,N,N,,,N,N,,N,,Y,variable valve timing at inlet and o
utlet valves,Y,variable valve lift at inlet valves,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GDI,
Spark Ignition Direct Injection,,Y,0W30,34.3,7,7,,DBMXJ02.0N20,5,600,
2013,BMW,BMW,Z4 sDrive28i,BMX,429,2,4,Manual(M6),22,34,26,28.3664,48.0364,34.774
1,22.2841,34.0033,26.3746,,TC,Turbocharged,M,Manual,6,N,N,R,10,GP,Gasoline (Prem
ium Unleaded Recommended),MPG,N,,,,,,,2200,2200,2,2,1,Two Seaters,car,Derived 5-
cycle label,7/25/12,11092,,N,N,,,N,N,,N,,Y,variable valve timing at inlet and ou
tlet valves,Y,variable valve lift at inlet valves,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GDI,S
park Ignition Direct Injection,,Y,0W30,34.9,7,7,,DBMXJ02.0N20,5,600,
2013,BMW,BMW,Z4 sDrive35i,BMX,436,3,6,Auto(AM-S7),17,24,19,21.1097,32.8224,25.14
8,16.8973,23.5833,19.3682,,TC,Turbocharged,AMS,Automated Manual- Selectable (e.g
. Automated Manual with paddles),7,N,N,R,10,GP,Gasoline (Premium Unleaded Recomm
ended),MPG,N,,,,,,,3000,3000,2,2,1,Two Seaters,car,Derived 5-cycle label,8/7/12,
12492,,N,N,,,N,N,,N,,Y,variable valve timing at inlet and outlet valves,N,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GDI,Spark Ignition Direct Injection,,Y,0W30,25.3,4,4,,DBMXV0
3.054R,5,,3400
2013,BMW,BMW,Z4 sDrive35i,BMX,435,3,6,Manual(M6),19,26,21,23.3,36.6,27.855,18.54
45,26.1997,21.352,,TC,Turbocharged,M,Manual,6,N,N,R,10,GP,Gasoline (Premium Unle
aded Recommended),MPG,N,,,,,,,2700,2700,2,2,1,Two Seaters,car,Derived 5-cycle la
bel,8/7/12,11743,,N,N,,,N,N,,N,,Y,variable valve timing at inlet and outlet valv
es,N,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,GDI,Spark Ignition Direct Injection,,Y,0W30,28.1,
5,5,,DBMXV03.054R,5,,1900
```

Comment: Show some sample content from your `temp.log` file?

Comment: everything you describe in your specification can be handled in 1 awk program. But first try `echo "$output"`. An unquote variable passed to `echo` will reduce all whitespace to a single space between each words. To get your 20 line header, just use awk's NR (Record Number) variable like `if (NR % 20) {print "header}`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Just quote the `$output`

```
echo "$output"
```

Additionally, you may want to get rid of redundant use of `cat` and do

```
awk -F ':' '{print $1 "\t" $4 "\t"$5"\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $3}' ./temp.log
```

instead

Comment: ... and set the `OFS` to make `awk` cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Try using column -t

```
echo $output | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo function to display a header every nth line like so:

```
$ seq 1 12 > moo 
$ awk < moo 'NR%4==0 { print "\nheading\n" } {print} 
             END{ print "total lines: " NR}'
1
2
3

heading

4
5
6
7

heading

8
9
10
11

heading

12
total lines: 12
```